# Agrupar datos en intervalos en R

Tags: r

tengo que organizar mil datos que están en un archivo de texto en 10 categorías, ya logré importar los datos a R, y cree los intervalos pero no sé como organizar los datos en estos intervalos, lo que necesito saber es cuantos datos hay en cada intervalo. Espero que me puedan ayudar.

```
# establecer el directorio de trabajo
setwd(dir = "C:/Users/DELL/Documents/Texto/")

# importar base de datos en el objeto llamado base_de_datos
base_de_datos <- read.table(file = "taller03_datos.txt")

# extraer los valores de la varible en el objeto llamado cal
cal <- base_de_datos$V1

# tamaño de la muestra
n <- length(cal)

#Máximo y Mínimo
Max <- max(cal)
Min <- min(cal)

#Rango
R <- Max - Min

#promedio aritmético
M <- mean(cal)

#amplitud del intervalo
a <- R/10

#intervalos
li <- seq(from=Min, to= Max-a, by=a)
ls <- seq(from=Min+a, to= Max, by=a)

# Marca de clase
Mc <- (li+ls)/2

# Frecuencia absoluta

#Tabla
tabla <- cbind(li,ls)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si te entiendo bien, creo que te has complicado la vida, lo que buscas es la frecuencia por los 10 intervalos equidistantes. Imaginemos una variable con 1000 observaciones que puede tener distintos valores:

```
set.seed(2020)
variable <- runif(1000)
```

Simplemente, podemos usar `cut()` para "cortar" la muestra en una cantidad deseada de porciones, luego sí, con `table()` podremos contar cuantos valores se lleva cada proción:

```
table(cut(variable, 10))

(-0.000105,0.101]     (0.101,0.201]       (0.201,0.3]         (0.3,0.4]         (0.4,0.5] 
              112                93                99                96               115 
        (0.5,0.6]         (0.6,0.7]         (0.7,0.8]       (0.8,0.899]         (0.899,1] 
              107                95                88               104                91
```

Comment: Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Para dividir una distribución de probabilidad en grupos "iguales" calculamos los cuantiles, en este caso, los deciles? ya que queremos dividir la distribucion en 10 partes, que nos será muy útil para realizar un diagrama de caja por grupos similares  y observar los outliers.

quantile(Table$Variable,prob=c(0,0.10,0.20,0.30,0.40,0.50,0.60,0.70,0.80,0.90)

#por otro lado, si dividimos la distribución en 5 partes, tendremos los quintiles. útil para realizar 5 grupos de datos.

quantile(Tabla$Variable,prob=c(0,0.20,0.4,0.6,0.8,1))

#Otra agrupación importante, que tiene que ver con los valores sigma

quantile(Table$Variable,prob=c(0.6826,0.9546,0.9973,0.999937,0.9999943,0.99999998))

No sé si es exáctamente lo que buscas.